# what player on windows can play mp4 with another audio channel file as track 2?

Tags: mp4

i want to play an mp4 file or a blu ray rip with another audio channel as a separate file, can that be done in vlc or another player? if so how? without having to convert/merge it with the video into a single file, I just want to stream them in one player... Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[Media Player Classic Home Cinema](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/) is an open source media player which is based on Media Player Classic which in turn was based on Windows Media Player 6.4 (i.e. before MS bloated up Media Player)

You can open a media file and dub in alternative / additional audio streams without having to remux (create a new file)

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem by using YAMB and creating a new mp4 by merging
http://www.free-codecs.com/download/Yamb.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with most video editing software such as [Cinefx](http://www.cinefx.org). Simply import the media and drag it onto the timeline. You can them play them together in the preview pane:

[image]

Supported filetypes:

> Input Files: AVI, DV, MOV, MP2, MP3,
>   MP4, MPG, OGG/OGM 
> Output Files: AVI,
>   DV, MOV, MP2, MP3, MP4, MPG, OGG/OGM

Cinefx is freeware.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Smplayer, just open your video, click on audio menu, choose open file, browse to the location of the audio file you want to use, and open it.